# A Haskell function of type: IO String-> String

Tags: haskell, io, monads, readfile

I wrote a bunch of code in Haskell to create an index of a text. The top function looks like this:

```
index :: String -> [(String, [Integer])]
index a = [...]
```

Now I want to give this function a String read from a file:

```
index readFile "input.txt"
```

Which won't work because readFile is of type FilePath -> IO String.

> Couldn't match expected type 'String'
>   against inferred type 'IO String'

I see the error, but I can't find any function with type:

```
IO String -> String
```

I guess the key to success lies somewhere under some Monads, but I could not find a way to solve my problem.

Comment: Take a look here for a good monad tutorial: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html

Comment: Other good resources can be found here in SO. Just look at the Related section, right-down on your screen.

Comment: ...here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154518

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can easily enough write a function that calls the readFile action, and passes the result to your index function.

```
readAndIndex fileName = do
    text <- readFile fileName
    return $ index text
```

However, the IO monad taints everything that uses it, so this function has the type:

```
readAndIndex :: FilePath -> IO [(String, [Integer])]
```

Comment: It's just a small sentence: "the IO monad taints everything that uses it". I did assume this was the case, but it's nice to see it confirmed now. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 29):

There is a very good reason why there is no such function.

Haskell has the notion of functional purity. This means that a function will always return the same result when called with the same parameters. The **only** place where IO is allowed is inside the IO monad.

If there was* a function

```
index :: IO String -> String
```

then we could suddenly do IO actions *anywhere* by calling, for example:

```
index (launchMissiles >> deleteRoot >> return "PWNd!")
```

Functional purity is a very useful feature that we don't want to lose, since it allows the compiler to reorder and inline functions much more freely, they can be sparked off to different cores without changing the semantics and it also gives the programmers a sense of security since if you can know what a function can and can't do from it's type.

* Actually there *is* such a function. It's called `unsafePerformIO` and it's called that for *very, very* good reasons. *Do not use it unless you're 100% sure of what you are doing!*

Comment: I would go as far as saying "Do not use it unless you're 200% sure of what you are doing", or, even simpler, "Do not".

Comment: I would say the best use for unsafePerformIO is to shell out to some process that should always return the same thing. ie a system computation not natively supported by the standard library.

Comment: Adding to my old comment that I just found while browsing around SO: Also useful for FFI

Answer (score 16):

Well you cannot get rid of the `IO` monad part of `IO String`. That means you will have to make your function return `IO [(String, [Integer])]`.

I recommend learning more about monads, but for now you can get away with the `liftM` function:

```
liftM index (readFile "input.txt")
```

`liftM` has this signature:

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

It takes a non-monadic function and transforms it into a monadic function.

Answer (score 9):

```
fmap index $ readFile "input.txt"
```

or

```
readFile "input.txt" >>= return . index
```

You may want to look into monad and functors