# Concatenate String and IO Integer in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, io, integer, concatenation

I wrote a function returning the current screen width as IO Integer (working so far).

```
getScreenWidth:: IO Integer
getScreenWidth = do
                    (sx, sy, w, h) <- getScreenDim 0
                    return $ sx
```

Now I would like to add the screen width to a string:

```
> magic_function :: IO Integer -> String -> ... magic output type
> magic_function = ... ? this is where i am stack at ? ...
```

I would like to pass the magic function to a string, something like "Screen Width: " and i want it to add the current screen width, so that i get "Screen Width: 1680". How can i concat an IO Integer and a common String? Does it work with `show`?

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting IO Int to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235348/converting-io-int-to-int)

Comment: No, its not an duplicate. I dont want to transform an IO type to a non IO Type, I want to concat an IO Int with a String. I know how to concat a string and an integer though....
And sadly the solution mentioned there doesnt work for me. Do I have to translate the String to an IO String maybe? And then concat IO String and IO Integer?

Comment: @user2316484 If you know the answer to one, you know the answer to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, forget about the IO:

```
labelInteger :: String -> Integer -> String
labelInteger label number = label ++ ": " ++ show number
```

Now worry about the IO:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM, liftM2)

labelIOInteger :: String -> IO Integer -> IO String
labelIOInteger label ioNumber = liftM (labelInteger label) ioNumber
```

Use as e.g. `labelIOInteger "Screen Width" getScreenWidth`... but beware! If you do something like this:

```
widthLabel <- labelIOInteger "Screen width" getScreenWidth
isPortrait <- liftM2 (<) getScreenWidth getScreenHeight
```

...then `getScreenWidth` will be executed twice... which admittedly for this particular action is unlikely to be a problem, but if it was an action that read an integer from a file or a database or a website, you can see that executing it twice might be undesirable.

It is usually better not to write functions like `labelIOInteger`, and instead do this:

```
widthLabel <- liftM (labelInteger "Screen Width") getScreenWidth
```

...so that if you find yourself needing to use the return value for two different calculations, you can easily refactor to this:

```
screenWidth <- getScreenWidth
let widthLabel = labelInteger "Screen Width" screenWidth
isPortrait <- liftM (screenWidth <) getScreenHeight
```

Answer (score 2):

```
magic_function :: IO Integer -> String -> IO String
magic_function num msg = do
                            n <- num
                            return (msg ++ (show n))
```

Answer (score 2):

The suggested duplicate *does* actually give the answer you need, but I suppose if it was obvious how you wouldn't be asking this in the first place. :]

In general, you can't do anything directly with a value whose type is `IO something`. This type represents not a value of type `something` wrapped in `IO`, but rather a procedure possibly using `IO` that produces a value of type `something` when executed. It may be different "something"s if you use the `IO something` value more than once, after all.

So in your case, you can't simply concatenate the `String` on; you have to define a new `IO` procedure that executes the other one, then concatenates the value it produces. The general form will look something like this:

```
someFunction :: a -> b -> c
someFunction a b = ...

someProcedure :: IO a -> b -> IO c
someProcedure a b = do aValue <- a -- this executes "a"
                       return $ someFunction aValue b
```

There are shorter ways to write it, but I thought it would help to spell it out. The specifics will depend on what you're actually doing, of course--for your program, you can use `show` to convert the integer to a `String`, then concatenate the strings like usual.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
magic :: IO Integer -> String -> IO String
magic ios s =
  do i <- ios
     return $ s ++ ": " ++ (show i)
```