# Haskell - sum of integers read from keyboard

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that sums integers supplied one per line and stops when 0 is input. I have this so far:

```
getInt :: IO Int          
getInt = do  
  s <- getLine
  return (read s)

sumInts :: IO Int
sumInts = do
  x<-getInt
  if x==0 then return 0 else return (x+sumInts)
```

but I get an error when I try to run it:

> couldn't match expected type Int with actual type IO Int

Comment: You must convert the IO integer to a int.

[Convert IO int to int][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235348/converting-io-int-to-int

Comment: The compiler errror is pretty straightforward. `sumInts` is an IO action, so instead of `return`ing, `fmap (+x) sumInts` or similar.

Comment: If you need more help please ask :)

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru I understood what the problem was and it works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I mean if you need more help on learning Haskell :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to add Int with IO Int in `(x+sumInts)`.

Let's take this step by step:

getInt return an actions that when it's executed returns an "Int" and you execute it using `<-` :

```
x<-getInt
```

That means x have type `Int`.

In expression `(x+sumInts)` you use `+` which have a type of:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Haskell interfer the type and replace `a` with the type of x, which means `+` will have type of:

```
 (+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

and will expect as second parameter an `Int`.

You are providing as the second parameter `sumInts` which have a type `IO Int` and that's why you have that error `couldn't match expected type Int with actual type IO Int`.

To make it works you have to "get out" the value from IO action using `<-` like this:

```
sumInts :: IO Int
sumInts = do
  x<-getInt
  if x==0 
    then return 0 
    else do
         rest <- sumInts
         return (x+rest)
```

Another approach to solve ths, in a more readable, is using Applicative:

```
import Control.Applicative

getInt :: IO Int          
getInt = do  
  s <- getLine
  return (read s)

sumInts :: IO Int
sumInts = do
  x<-getInt
  if x==0 then return 0 else (x+) <$> sumInts
```

The `<$>` function takes a function (in our case `x+`) an apply it on value inside an Applicative Functor (IO is instance of Applicative and Functor) and return that Functor with computation applied.
Type of `<$>` is:

```
> :t (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and for IO this will be :

```
(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
(<$>) :: (Int -> Int) -> IO Int -> IO Int -- If we consider that a is an Int
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
x<-getInt
if x==0 then return 0 else return (x+sumInts)
```

`x` has a type `Int`, but `sumInts` is `IO Int`. 
I would recommend separating the IO part and the calculation part into different functions.