# TVar constructor? I can't get a TVar

Tags: haskell, stm, tvar

I'm new at Haskell and stm and I wanted to make a simple rwlock. First I created the 4 main functions (wlock, wunlock, rlock, runlock) that requires 2 TVar Integers: the amount of reading threads and writing threads.

At this point I can't use it as intended. I try to compile like this

```
v1 <- atomically(newTVar 0);
v2 <- atomically(newTVar 0);
wlock v1 v2 -- wlock :: TVar Integer -> TVar Integer -> IO ()
```

which of course is ugly, but it works (not sure why because atomically returns `IO (TVar a)` instead of `TVar a`)

**What I want:**

I'm trying to make it better by hiding the values. I read somewhere that monads might be the way to go, but I haven't study them yet. Instead, I try to make a new type Rwlock as

```
data Rwlock = Rwlock {  readCant :: TVar Integer 
    ,writeCant :: TVar Integer
}
```

and a constructor, so I can do something like this:

```
import Rwlock

do{
    a = rwconst;
    forkIO(reader a);
    forkIO(writer a);
}
```

where reader will call `rlock a`, and writer `wlock a`.

**The problem:**

I can't make the constructor. This is what I try (ignore `maxLectores` )

(A):

```
rwconst :: Integer -> Rwlock
rwconst n = Rwlock {readCant = TVar 0, writeCant = TVar 0, maxLectores = n}
{-rwconst n = Rwlock {readCant = atomically(newTVar 0), writeCant = atomically(newTVar 0), maxLectores = n}-}
```

But TVar constructor is not exported, and nothing returns a TVar. I don't know why the first block of code works when I do `wlock v1 v2`, but this way it doesn't.

And (B):

```
rwconst :: Integer -> Rwlock
rwconst n = do
    a <- (atomically(newTVar 0));
    Rwlock {readCant = a, writeCant = a, maxLectores = n}
```

Here Rwlock doesn't have a problem, but the do statement returns IO(), instead of Rwlock as I want, and I can't found how to do it.

Anyone can tell me the way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235348/converting-io-int-to-int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allocating locks requires doing IO, and you can't get around that. So admit it in the type for your action:

```
rwconst :: Integer -> IO Rwlock
rwcost n = do
    rcount <- newTVarIO 0
    wcount <- newTVarIO 0
    return Rwlock { readCant = rcount, writeCant = wcount, maxLectores = n }
```

Then, in `main`, you can write something like this:

```
main = do
    a <- rwconst 10
    forkIO (reader a)
    forkIO (writer a)
    -- and you should do something to wait for reader and writer to finish
```