# If statement using IO Int haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming, haskell-stack, io-monad

I have a game , user vs computer and I want to randomly choose who starts the game. I have

```
a = getStdRandom $ randomR (0, 1)
```

This gets a random number 0 or 1. However it is a `IO Int`, so I can't have an if statement comparing it to a number like

```
if a == 0 then userStarts else computerStarts
```

I have tried to compare `IO Int` with `IO Int` and it doesn't work, and I have also tried

[Converting IO Int to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235348/converting-io-int-to-int)

I am very new to Haskell, not sure how to approach this. Code details requested:

```
randomNumber =  getStdRandom $ randomR (0, length symbols - 5) --  this will be 0 or 1
randomNumber2 =  getStdRandom $ randomR (0, length symbols - 5) -- according to 
                     -- the solution I need another function returning IO int.

a = do
   x <- randomNumber
   randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x
```

Error I get:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> IO b
                  with actual type ‘IO Int’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
      but its type ‘IO Int’ has none
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x
      In the expression:
        do x <- randomNumber
           randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x

    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: IO b
          (bound at Path:87:1)

    randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x

Path:89:20: error:
    Variable not in scope: pureFunction :: Int -> t0

     randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x
```

Comment: have you tried using a `do` block as recommended by the first answer to the linked question? Because that (along with the `>>=` operator, for which the `do` block is just syntactic sugar) is the only way to do it.

Comment: I tried but I get the error that pureFunction is not in scope, and why do I need two functions returning an IO int?

Comment: An `Int` is a fixed, constant integer value, An `IO Int` is essentially a routine which can be called many times, and which will generate an integer value each time (potentially, distinct values will be returned). `do` blocks, applicative/monadic helpers, etc. help in calling that routine and get the actual integer, roughly put.

Comment: For `randomNumber2 $ pureFunction x` to make sense you need `randomNumber2` to have type `Something -> IO Int` and `pureFunction` to be `Int -> Something`. `randomNumber2` is just `IO Int`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522491/is-there-a-way-to-place-some-impure-code-inside-pure-functions .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say `a = getStdRandom $ randomR (0,1)` you are saying "let a be the action of getting a random value between 0 and 1".  What you want is within some function's do block `a <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0,1)` which is "let a be the result of running the action of getting a random value between 0 and 1".

As such:

```
import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0, 1 :: Int)
  if a == 0 then userStarts else computerStarts

-- Placeholders for completeness
userStarts, computerStarts :: IO ()
userStarts = putStrLn "user"
computerStarts = putStrLn "computer"
```

N.B. I specified the `1` is an int or else the compiler won't know if you want a random int, int64, double, float, or something else entirely.

EDIT: @monocell makes a good point that generating an int in a range just to get a boolean is somewhat indirect.  You can just directly generate a boolean result and this requires no range:

```
  a <- getStdRandom random
  if a then userStarts else computerStarts
```

Comment: Maybe mention that `Bool` has a `Random` instance?

Comment: `Bool` has a random instance.

Comment: Hehe, very funny. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your code looks like, but have you tried doing what the linked resource recommends (using the do block)?

```
do
   (result, newGenerator) <- randomR (0, 1) generator
   -- ...
```

That will get you access to `result`, which is of the same type as `0` and `1`.

Can you show your code/the error you get?