# transforming IO String to String

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads

I am having an issue converting  IO String() to a String()
Below is the function to eval an expression.

```
foobar :: String -> IO String

eval :: String -> Sh () ()
eval x =  do
 s <- foobar x
 shellPutStrLn $ s
```

This isnt working, because eval returns IO String instead of Sh. The
moment some IO is done within a function it transforms/taints it into
IO String.
How do I prevent the transformation  or convert an IO String to String ?

Comment: What do you mean by IO String()? If you mean `IO String ()` that's not a valid type, and neither is `String()`.

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/practical-haskell/ ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting IO Int to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235348/converting-io-int-to-int) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675366/a-haskell-function-of-type-io-string-string and hundred other similar questions. Please use search

Comment: @Landei - The title is similar, but the problem's context is different and so is the solution.  I don't think either of the questions you link to are appropriate as duplicates.  Although this may be a duplicate of a monad transformer question...

Comment: Over on Math.SE, they have something called 'abstract duplicates' for this kind of almost-but-not-quite repitition.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your `Sh` type is supposed to be able to do IO.  The usual way to implement this is with monad transformers.  Then you would have:

```
instance MonadIO Sh where -- definition elided because you don't show Sh

shellPutStrLn :: String -> Sh ()
shellPutStrLn = liftIO . putStrLn

eval :: String -> Sh ()
eval x = do
  s <- liftIO $ foobar x
  shellPutStrLn s
```

See the [MTL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) for a lot of ready monad transformers you can use, and [xmonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad) for a good example of this style in practice.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If it solved your problem, would you consider accepting this answer?

Answer (score 3):

This "tainting" of your string is deliberate and cannot be avoided without resorting to dirty hacks. You can extract the `String` temporarily, however, provided you put the result back in `IO` when you're done. For example

```
foobar :: String -> IO String

baz :: String -> IO Int
baz str = do
    result <- foobar str
    return (length result)
```

I would recommend reading up on Haskell IO

- [Real World Haskell: Input and Output](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html).
- [Haskell IO without monads](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2010/01/haskell-io-without-monads.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you are operating within some monad any time you use the 'do notation'. For example, the code below operates within the IO monad:

```
printThem x y = do
    print ("x: " ++ show x)
    print ("y: " ++ show y)
```

You can't mix monads in the same 'do' block. This is what you are attempting here.

```
eval :: String -> Sh () ()
eval x =  do          -- Which monad? There can be only one!
    s <- foobar x     -- IO monad
    shellPutStrLn $ s -- Sh monad
```

You will have to execute `foobar` in an outer layer. Use something like the following. I don't know where your `Sh` monad is coming from, so I'll just pretend that there is a `runShell :: Sh () -> IO ()` function:

```
doSomeIO :: IO ()
doSomeIO = do
    s <- foobar x
    runShell $ shellPutStrLn s
```