# How to convert data from IO(String) to String in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io, monads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Haskell function of type: IO String-> String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675366/a-haskell-function-of-type-io-string-string)

i'm reading some data from a file using the `readFile` function available in Haskell. But this function returns me some data stored as `IO String`. Does anybody knows how do I convert this data into a `String` type (or any function that reads `String` from a file, without the `IO ()` type)?

Comment: While this is definitely a duplicate, I have to wonder..  What makes people think there's such a thing as a function that makes an action that does IO to get a string not do IO?

Comment: It is a general misconception of side effects.

Comment: I think it has less to do with side effects than it does that almost everyone uses monads before they understand them.

Answer (score 19):

It is a very general question about extracting data from monadic values.

The general idea is to use `>>=` function:

```
main = readFile foo >>= \s -> print s
```

`>>=` takes 2 arguments. It extracts the value from its first argument and passes it to its second argument. The first argument is monadic value, in this case of type `IO String`, and the second argument is a function that accepts a plain, non-monadic value, in this case `String`.

There is a special syntax for this pattern:

```
main = do
   s <- readFile foo
   print s
```

But the meaning is the same as above. The `do` notation is more convenient for beginners and for certain complicated cases, but explicit application of `>>=` can lead to a shorter code. For example, this code can be written as just

```
main = readFile foo >>= print
```

Also there are a big family of library functions to convert between monadic and non-monadic values. The most important of them are `return`, `fmap`, `liftM2` and `>=>`.

The concept of monad is very useful beyond representing IO in a referentially transparent way: these helpers are very useful for error handling, dealing with implicit state and other applications of monads.

The second most important monad is `Maybe`.

Comment: `most of the time the explicit application of >>= leads to a better code` - i wonder how you could substantiate this claim. Nevertheless, +1 for good explanation.

Comment: "most of the time" and "better" are stop words. Thank you for spotting them. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd treat the IO type as a [functor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors#Functors) in this case, and instead of getting the value out of it, I'd send my function inside it and let the `Functor` instance deal with creating a new IO container with the result from my function.

```
> :m +Data.Functor
> length <$> readFile "file.txt"
525
```

`<$>` is an alias for `fmap`. I like `<$>` more, but it's just a personal preference.

Comment: That's not a wrong answer, however when someone is starting to _trying_ to understand the concept of monadic values, you can't throw *Applicative Functors* to them without getting them even more confused.

Comment: @RomanGonzalez true, but I'm not sure he can get a good grasp of this without being confused in the beginning. And I don't want to write a course either. Not here/now at least. Small correction, what I've used is just a functor, not an applicative functor. The module name is misleading indeed. Maybe I should have used `Data.Functor`... Oh, and I think that `Functor` should be thought before `Monad`. It makes more sense.