# Convert a Monadic value to Non-monadic

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod

I am new to Haskell.
I need to read the contents from a directory (i.e list all the files in the directory) and convert it to HTML.
I have a codebase which uses the Yesod framework.

Now, I was able to read the directory contents using `getDirectoryContents` which returns type of `IO [FilePath]`. I want to be able to represent this in HTML.

Can someone help me on this? So far this is what I have tried. 
The error that I get is:
`Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM’
      Expected type: Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM Html
        Actual type: IO Html`

Please check the code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

import Yesod.Core
import Text.Blaze.Html (toValue, (!))
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as HA
import System.Directory as FS



getTestHamletR = defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Test Hamlet"
    toWidget $ \render -> do
           H.p $ do
                result <- fmap toHtml $ getListOfFiles "/home/chetan"
                result
```

Here is the `getListOfFiles` function:

```
getListOfFiles::FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getListOfFiles fpath = FS.getDirectoryContents fpath
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675366/a-haskell-function-of-type-io-string-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Haskell function of type: IO String-> String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675366/a-haskell-function-of-type-io-string-string)

Comment: The error you see is because `fmap toHtml $ getListOfFiles "/home/chetan"` has type `IO (MarkupM ())`, since `type Html = MarkupM ()` in the blaze-html library.  However, the `H.p` function has type `Html -> Html`, so it takes a `MarkupM ()` and returns a new `MarkupM ()`.  You're giving it a `IO (MarkupM ())`, so the compiler complains.  You'll have to do the `getListOfFiles` outside of your blaze code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not well versed in Yesod, but this should work.

You cannot convert an `IO` value to non-IO value. However, you can work with these values, while staying in `IO`. To say it somewhat incorrectly, you can work with these values while being inside IO. I.e. this should work (not-tested):

```
getTestHamletR = do
    files <- liftIO $ getListOfFiles "/home/chtan"
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Test Hamlet"
        toWidget $ \render -> do
           H.p $ toHtml (intercalate ", " files)
```

I guess that `getTestHamletR` is not directly `IO`, but it is some layer above `IO`, so we can use `liftIO` to convert the `IO [FilePath]` to `m [FilePath]` where `m` is the Monad yesod uses.

The `getTestHamletR` is an `IO` function - every line works inside `IO`, you get the directory contents as `IO [FilePath]` and you essentially convert it to `IO Html`.

Comment: Thanks. H.p does not work on [Html]. It works on Html only. I am getting the related error which mentions it. Any idea how I could fix it

Comment: That depends on you - you have a list of files and want to convert it to html. The function `toHtml` converts e.g. a `String` to html, so e.g. in this example I have concatenated the strings together. Import the `interacalate` from `Data.List`.