# Why does this IO-Handling not work (IO (Either a b))

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to extract "a" and the error "b" from an expression of the type IO (Either a b).

I have this function, which returns a parsed file based on the file path

```
readFile' :: FilePath -> IO (Either a b)
```

And that's the way I'm trying to extract the values of a and b:

```
rFile :: FilePath -> String
rFile f = do
            l <- readFile' f
            case l of 
               Right n -> show n
               Left m  -> show m
```

This is the error message:

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
  Expected type: [Either a b]
    Actual type: IO (Either a b)
* In a stmt of a 'do' block: l <- readFile' f
```

Answer (score 5):

`rFile` can't return a `String` value, only an `IO String` value. (Or more precisely, the result of the do construct must be an `IO String` value, not a `String`.)

```
rFile :: FilePath -> IO String
rFile f = do
            l <- readFile' f
            return $ case l of 
               Right n -> show n
               Left m  -> show m
```

You can use `fmap` and `either` to get rid of both the explicit case analysis and the do syntax.

```
rFile f = fmap (either show show) (readFile' f)
```

(The obvious follow-up question, how do I get a `String` from an `IO String`, is one I'm not going to rehash here. For all practical intents and purposes, you don't.)

Comment: [Here's that follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675366/15207568)